# Kafka producer code in jenkins not able to send data to confluent kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jenkins-pipeline, kafka-producer-api, confluent-cloud

I have a java file in maven project that contains Kafka producer code to send data to a topic.

```
Producer.java
// some code

KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);

JSONObject jsonRecord = new JSONObject();
jsonRecord.put("integer", 1);
try {
    RecordMetadata recordMetadata = producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName, null,
                            mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonRecord))).get();
    System.out.println("metadata - topic: " + recordMetadata.topic());
} 
catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error occurred" + e.getMessage());
}

// some code
```

I run this file using the command

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=Producer
```

The properties are:

```
public static final String JAAS_SASL_TEMPLATE =
            "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"%s\" %s=\"%s\";"
props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_SSL");
String jaasCfg = String.format(JAAS_SASL_TEMPLATE, "username", "auth_secret_key", "kafka_secret");
props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "PLAIN");
props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, jaasCfg);
props.put(CommonClientConfigs.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "example.aws.confluent.cloud:9092");       
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class.getName());
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
```

This code is able to send data to the confluent Kafka topic when I run it locally

Now I have added a stage in the Jenkins pipeline to run the java file inside a shell script

```
stage('Send data') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                  mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=Producer
                  '''
                }
            }
```

All the other functionality works but Kafka producer is not able to send data to confluent Kafka topic. No error is thrown either. Can someone please help me with what I am missing??

Comment: You need to provide the security tokens for the cluster

Comment: @OneCricketeer Please check the description..have added security tokens of the cluster..but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Singular records are not immediately sent. Have you tried `producer.flush()` or `producer.send(...).get()` and printing the callback metadata?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Please check the updated code..I have used `producer.send(...).get()` but I am not getting any metadata or exception.

Comment: What _does_ get printed? Have you setup log4j correctly? Can you add more log statements?

Comment: @OneCricketeer..I am getting this error message `error occurred org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test_topic not present in metadata after 30000 ms.`..I dont get this error when I run in my local machine but only when I run the code from jenkins pipeline

Comment: Also, I am able to connect to the cluster from jenkins node because I checked this command `telnet example.aws.confluent.cloud 9092` on the node

Comment: Overall, seems like a network and/or permissions issue. Are you able to run `kafka-topics --describe --topic test_topic` from Jenkins?